# Twilio - Media Streams with DTMF tones

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

Is it possible to receive the DTMF tones via websocket, when using media streams?

I'm able to get the audio stream and do whatever I want with it, such as calling a SpeechToText service in real time, but now I'm taking the next step and trying to get DTMF detection working, does Twilio send the tones via websocket as it does the audio?

If it doesn't, are there any solutions, such as using a Gather dtmf with a stream inside? I've seen someone else trying that without success.

Comment: The Twilio Media Stream sends a stream of all the audio sent through the call, so that will include the voice as well as DTMF tones as far as I know. Have you tested whether the DTMF tone is sent?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to answer to your comment (thank you). It doesn't look like the tones are sent via the stream